# updating list, set during iteration -- while loop

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I have a scrapy script as follows

1) Collects navigation_path into a list and calls a new parse

```
g_next_page_list = []
g_next_page_set = set()

def parse(self,response):

    #code to extract nav_links

    for nav_link in nav_links:
        if nav_link not in g_next_page_set:
            g_next_page_list.append(nav_link)
            g_next_page_set.add(nav_link)

    for next_page in g_next_page_list:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_start_url,  dont_filter=True, )
```

And i've defined parse_start_url as:

```
def parse_start_url(self,response):

    #code to extract nav_links

    for nav_link in nav_links:
        if nav_link not in g_next_page_set:
            g_next_page_list.append(nav_link)
            g_next_page_set.add(nav_link)
```

However, the global list and set in the main parse (g_next_page_set, g_next_page_list) are not getting appended. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `v_next_page_list` the same thing as `g_next_page_list` or are one of those a typo? And if they're different, please provide some sample data for `v_next_page_list`.

Comment: @supersam654 Sorry about the confusion. They're the same and i've updated my original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use global here, you use self.variable_name

```
g_next_page_list = []
g_next_page_set = set()

def parse(self,response):

    #code to extract nav_links

    for nav_link in nav_links:
        if nav_link not in v_next_page_set:
            self.g_next_page_list.append(nav_link)
            self.g_next_page_set.add(nav_link)

    for next_page in v_next_page_list:
        next_page = response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse_start_url,  dont_filter=True, )


def parse_start_url(self,response):

    #code to extract nav_links

    for nav_link in nav_links:
        if nav_link not in v_next_page_set:
            self.g_next_page_list.append(nav_link)
            self.g_next_page_set.add(nav_link)
```

This should make it work